# IApplication Builder does not contain a definition for UseWebpackDevMiddleware

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2019

I am following a tutorial to become familiar with server side rendering involving asp.net core and react, but I am hitting a roadblock on the HelloWorld.  I am doing this alongside another co-worker and he is not getting this same issue.  I have uninstalled and reinstalled all dependencies with npm to make sure there were no installation issues.

I have tried to find some answer as to what I am missing, an import etc, but cannot seem to find anyone with the same exact issue.  I had looked at similar IApplicationBuilder exceptions but the solutions they usually have is try this import statement etc etc.  I have uninstalled and reinstalled all my dependencies with npm. I have recreated the project three times

Below is the Configure method from my Startup.cs file.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
```

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) {
    if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware();
    } else {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        app.UseHsts();
    }
}
```

app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(); is throwing the following error:
"Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1061  'IApplicationBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'UseWebpackDevMiddleware' and no accessible extension method 'UseWebpackDevMiddleware' accepting a first argument of type 'IApplicationBuilder' could be found"

Answer (score 0):

In Package Manager run Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions