# HttpModule based plugin migration to .net core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-3, httpmodule

I have a .net framework 4.7 project which is essentially an HTTPmodule to be used independantly in IIS server to detect incoming requests and responses, to 3rd party applications installed in IIS,which then need to be modified.

We were adding the module using the webconfig for the respective applications.However now i am migrating it to .net core 6.we use a sample web api to test the httpmodule project.However it seems the addition has to be in startup.cs of the sample web app.

**Issue:-**
1.I add a middlware to the 1st project like below

```
 using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
 using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Myspace.HttpModule.Example
{
    // You may need to install the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions package into your project
    public class MyMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        

        public MyMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
        {

            

            return _next(httpContext);
        }
    }

    // Extension method used to add the middleware to the HTTP request pipeline.
    public static class MyMiddlewareExtensions
    {
        public static IApplicationBuilder UseMyMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
        {
            return builder.UseMiddleware<MyMiddleware>();
        }
    }
}
```

2.Now i need to add this to the 2nd project which is the sample web app to test the HTTPModule.However when i try to add it to the startup.cs file that i created in the sample web app project

```
using Myspace.HttpModule.Example;
using System.Globalization;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();



var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
    
}



app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseMiddleware<MyMiddleware>();

app.UseMyMiddleware();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

I get compilation errors at

```
app.UseMiddleware<MyMiddleware>();
    
app.UseMyMiddleware();
```

**So is it that i cant add like this.Wouldnt "using" work in this case?
Also is this the only way to add a middleware to be able to get requests globally or from the specific sample or 3rd party app?
I googled a lot but couldn't find piece together a definite answer. I am a newbie to .Net**

The error is like below

[image]

Update:-

The error image is

[image]

Comment: Could you show the detailed  message  of the error

Comment: Edited the question with the error shown

Comment: is this relevant to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56868082/iapplication-builder-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-usewebpackdevmiddleware

Comment: The method should be inclued in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder in your project when you create the project, please check as below

Answer (score 0):

the method should be included in

namespace `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder`

assembly:`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions.dll`
[image]
which was included in Microsoft.AspNetCore.app in your project when you created the project :

[image]

please check the framewok if there's something wrong with it

Comment: I added this dependency which was missing in project 1 and 2 and rebuilt.Yet says "The namespace xxx could not be found."

Comment: it may help if you could upload your project to github and we could research what get wrong

Answer (score 0):

your screenshot is pointing to a spelling mistake. its UseMiddleware not Middelware as it can be seen in your screenshot.
please check if you are using correct name.

and also you only need to use either

```
app.UseMiddleware<MyMiddleware>();
```

or

```
app.UseMyMiddleware();
```

not both.

Comment: I checked.i rebuilt and the error says -The type or namespace "MyMiddleware" could not be found.I have updated the latest image in the question.And i have used a single app.UseMiddleware<MyMiddleware>();

Comment: can you add this project as github repo so that we can pull and check what is the issue.

Comment: Sorry for delayed reply.Had to look into something else.Was able to fix this by using add project reference to the 1st project by rt click on visual studio.

Comment: glad. your problem got resolved..